# Calling Web API via OData implementation to return records that have a foreign key to another record - not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have two tables in SQL - one is called "ContactDetails" and the other is "Departments".  The relationship between the two are 1 to many.  1 ContactDetails record to many Department records.

I am using ASP.NET Web API with OData - this is my first time using OData, so the solution to my question is probably pretty simple (hopefully).

When I make the call to the Get() method on my Web API, the response I get is JSON (as expected), but as you can see, I only get the top level records (the ContactDetails records, and NOT the Departments records). What I obviously want are all the records from ContactDetails, and for each ContactDetails record, have an 'X' number of Department records beneath it. Here's my Get() method (and I'll also note that when I drill into the records here, I do in fact see all of the Department records tied to each ContactDetails record):

[image]

Here's what I am currently getting when I hit my Web API:

[image]

I suspect the problem may be how I define my ODataModelBuilder/EntitySet/etc. in my WebApiConfig.cs.  I hope there's something stupid simple I'm not doing that can be easily pointed out.  Here's how that is set up:

[image]

**QUESTION**
How do I get all records, including foreign key records, in my response?

Comment: I'm curious about who you work for. We are in a similar industry currently. : )

Comment: We might meet in the real world sometime. : )

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the "Expand" method.

[Previous Answer Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782342/expand-in-a-projection-select-for-wcf-data-services-odata)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: It does provide an answer to the question. Using the Expand method allows a client to pull down extended "Objects" in OData. Depending on the query though it can lead to a sizable reduction in speed for their request.  In an earlier Answer.. I actually suggested OData.. to Mike.. just a bit ago today.  So I do apologize for not giving a full and complete answer.. with example code.

Comment: I'm pretty sure .Expand() is in 4.5... I'm targeting 4.0.

Comment: It should be a part of the OData version 2 or higher.  http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-v2-documentation/uri-conventions/#46_Expand_System_Query_Option_expand

Comment: Just to be clear in addition.. it should be on your DataServices generated Client, and not a Linq method, or anything like that.

Comment: @SlackShot if you're talking about the $expand, I did that (http://localhost/AppName/Contact?$expand=Departments), and nothing.  Still, returning the same records, nothing additional.  I did see something in the Content-Type: odata=minimumodata (or something like that).  I changed that to verbose, and then I saw the Departments node, but there was nothing really underneath the node - it said "deferred", as in, didn't bring back those records.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7069882/is-it-possible-to-query-an-odata-service-and-expand-child-of-child-entities  You need to expand multiple levels. Like this referenced answer.  Working hard for these reputation points!

Comment: Oh, Woah, I am wrong.  I thought you had three entities. Contacts, ContactDetail, and Departments.